# Failed to fetch error on an API that requeres an OATH Bearer key

Tags: python, html

Just looking for advice on what a failed to fetch error might mean in this context, as I have tried local hosting a port, and not doing so. My original script included the bearer OATH key, but now that i have adapted my code to work with HTMX, I am unsure of where to include this information, or really, if it is even the cause of the error. Please let me know if anyone has any leads, I have included both the original(working) python script, as well as the  of my adapted HTML file.

```py
from cfbd.models import team
from cfbd.api.players_api import PlayersApi
import cfbd
import json

#access key
configuration = cfbd.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['Authorization'] = 'Enk...2A'
configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'


#player search parameter
search_term = "Deonte Banks"

#processes the request and prints the data of an individual player and their background
api_instance = cfbd.PlayersApi(cfbd.ApiClient(configuration))
response = api_instance.player_search(search_term = search_term)
print(response)
```

this script returns the following in .json format:

```json
[{'first_name': 'Deonte',
 'height': 74,
 'hometown': 'Edgewood, MD',
 'id': 4428328,
 'jersey': 3,
 'last_name': 'Banks',
 'name': 'Deonte Banks',
 'position': 'DB',
 'team': 'Maryland',
 'team_color': '#D5002B',
 'team_color_secondary': '#ffcd00',
 'weight': 205}]
```

However, when I adapted this to work in my body tag, I lost sight of something clearly, and have been receiving a "failed to fetch" error. This `<body>` code has been included below as well.

```html
<body>
    <form id="myForm" hx-post="javascript:submitForm()">
        <label for="firstNameInput">First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" name="firstNameInput">
        
        <label for="lastNameInput">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" name="lastNameInput">

        <button type="button" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#myDataTable" hx-swap="outerHTML">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>

    <div id="myDataTable">
        <!-- Table content will be populated dynamically -->
    </div>

    <script>
        function submitForm() {
            // Get values from the text inputs
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value;

            // Construct the API endpoint using the fetched values
            var apiEndpoint = `https://api.collegefootballdata.com/player/search?searchTerm=${firstName}%20${lastName}`;

            // Log the constructed API endpoint
            console.log('API Endpoint:', apiEndpoint);

            // Perform the API call with the constructed endpoint
            fetch(apiEndpoint)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    // Log the API response data
                    console.log('API Response:', data);

                    // Create an HTML table with the received data
                    var tableHTML = '<table><thead><tr><th>Player ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

                    data.forEach(player => {
                        tableHTML += `<tr><td>${player.id}</td><td>${player.firstName}</td><td>${player.lastName}</td></tr>`;
                        // Add more columns as needed
                    });

                    tableHTML += '</tbody></table>';

                    // Replace the content of the 'myDataTable' div with the generated HTML table
                    document.getElementById('myDataTable').innerHTML = tableHTML;
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I have tried a localhost port, as well as a simple run without debugging, and the localhost showed signs of life, even if it was an error, while the latter did not.